# GridView and RowDataBound event

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

I can edit single row in the **GridView**.

But when in MySQL database the value of field *"card"* is not null I need stopping the edit in this single row of  **GridView** (and passed the row in closed state).

I tried this solution, but in GridView I've all rows of GridView in **"closed state"** even when the value of field **"card" is null**, why?

The condition is inserted in *RowDataBound event*, it's correct?

My code below.

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var obj = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["card"];
        ImageButton edit = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("imgbtnEdit");

        if (obj != null)
        {
            edit.Enabled = false;
            edit.ToolTip = "Closed state";
        }
    }


    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)(e.Row.FindControl("ddlpages"));
        Label lblPageCount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblPageCount");

        if (lblPageCount != null)
            lblPageCount.Text = GridView1.PageCount.ToString();

        for (int i = 1; i <= GridView1.PageCount; i++)
        {
            ddl.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }

        ddl.SelectedIndex = GridView1.PageIndex;

        if (GridView1.PageIndex == 0)
        {
            ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton1")).Visible = false;
            ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton2")).Visible = false;
        }

        if (GridView1.PageIndex + 1 == GridView1.PageCount)
        {
            ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton3")).Visible = false;
            ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton4")).Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `DBNull.Value` and `null` are two different things.

```
var obj = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["card"];
if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(obj))
{
    edit.Enabled = false;
    edit.ToolTip = "Closed state";
}
```

This will check to see if the "card" value is a null database value, rather than a null object.